# Search function fails when changing from Lucene7.0 to Lucene 9.0

Tags: java, lucene

I was using Lucene 7.0 version to index files and search files and it went well, however when I changed the jar from Lucene 7 to Lucene 9, it fails at this line of code, and also gave me this error:

```java
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths
        .get("D:\\IdeaProjects\\Lucene7.0\\src\\index1\\documents.index")));
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 26 more
```

These are all the libs I use for the project. I first used Lucene-core-7.4, and then I changed to Lucene-core-9.0:

[image]

Comment: Java 9 is vastly different from Java 7. All your libraries and dependencies must be updated to support Java 9

Comment: I change the jar library, and IntelliJ does not give me any warnings, but it fails when I run it. I am not sure the indexing process goes well, but it failed at this line of codeIndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("D:\IdeaProjects\Lucene7.0\src\index1\documents.index")));

Comment: @Kwright02 - the question is about Lucene 7.0 and Lucene 9.0; not about Java 7.0 or Java 9.0. But your point is valid - one needs to update all the _Lucene_ JARs (not just one of them).

Comment: How are you managing your Lucene JARs? Manually, or using a tool such as Maven? Show us which Lucene JARs you are using (ideally as Maven POM dependencies) or just as a list of JARs, making it clear which JAR is from which version of Lucene.

Comment: I managed the jars manually by the project structure, and I put the image above in the link.

Comment: OK - but that screenshot shows you have _both_ `lucene-core-7.4.0.jar` _and_ `lucene-core-9.0.0.jar` at the same time - and you also have a list of other Lucene JARs which you have not upgraded. You need to upgrade _every_ Lucene JAR to v9.0.0. And you need to _remove_ every Lucene 7.4.0 JAR.  (And using Maven is much better, in the long run. It helps you to avoid these types of problem.)

Comment: And also, if you want to use Lucene 9 to open an index which was created using Lucene 7, you will probably need the [Lucene 9 Backward Codecs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-backward-codecs/9.0.0) JAR.